# Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net

Tags: vhdl

I wrote this code. I want to count the numbers that I pressed they key_0 and if I press 2 times then the red led will turn on, how ever I get this error:

> Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net.

The thing is that I try to torn on 2 process at the same time how ever this tow process have the same variable: duty_cycle_counter.

What is the problem?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity Pwm_control is

  generic(display_resolution : INTEGER := 8);

  port(
    key_0     : in  BIT;
    green_led : out BIT;
    red_led   : out BIT
  );
end Pwm_control;

architecture Behavioral of Pwm_control is

  signal counter         : std_logic_vector(display_resolution downto 0);
  signal general_counter : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0); -- general_counter is for the clock divider , can get till 23 

  signal step_10_dc         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0); --10 step PWM 
  signal step_5_dc          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0); --5 step PWM 
  signal starting_value_0   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0); --0 step PWM 
  signal duty_cycle_counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);

begin
  starting_value_0   <= "000000000";
  step_5_dc          <= "000011010";
  step_10_dc         <= "000110011";
  duty_cycle_counter <= "000000000";

  key_testing : process(key_0)        -- 
  begin
    if (key_0 = '0') then
      green_led          <= '1';
      duty_cycle_counter <= (duty_cycle_counter + step_5_dc);
    else
      green_led <= '0';
    end if;

  end process key_testing;

  key_test_red_led : process(duty_cycle_counter)
  begin
    if (step_10_dc <= duty_cycle_counter) then
      red_led <= '1';
    end if;
  end process key_test_red_led;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're driving `duty_cycle_counter` continuously with 0 *and* trying to update it in the `key_testing` process. It looks like you wanted a start value (possible in most RAM-based FPGAs) or a reset, though in real life it will have *some* value so you could just leave out the initialization.

Comment: I tried what you said  and it worked how ever for some reason i cant control the PWM each time I press the key 0 i get random PWM .

Comment: That might be a different issue. If you get any response from your button, it's probably time to look at how fast things respond and whether you need debouncing.

Comment: duty_cycle_counter is a latch enabled by key_0  It has feedback (duty_cycle_counter+step_5_dc) where at least one bit will invert each time making a gate oscillator. While you can't simulate a zero delay model faithfully, the closest you could comes would be to add duty_cycle_counter to the process sensitivity list. You'd expect simulation to encounter an implementation defined delta cycle limit. In addition to de-bouncing generate either an edge to use as a clock or one clock long enable for a register instead of a latch. The max value (511) also isn't a multiple of step_5_dc (26).

Comment: first of all thanks for the help , but I did add the duty_cycle_counter to the sensitivity list as you can see